# Function in R to cluster entries in a tables column

Tags: r, read.table

I have this input in R:

```
> table2[2]
   Describe.the.color.shown.in.the.image.below.
1                                  soft crimson
2                                     dark pink
3                                    watermelon
4                                     Light Red
5                                    dark coral
6                                          Rose
7                                         peach
8                               strawberry pink
9                                     light red
10                                         pink
11                                    light red
12                                       salmon
13                                    light red
14                                    light red
15                                         pink
16                                         pink
17                        light and unclear red
18                                   velvet red
19                                    light red
20                                       orange
21                                    light red
22                                   light  red
23                                    light red
24                                    dark pink
25                                   red orange
26                                         pink
```

and what I need to do is for example:

```
light red = 8/26
pink = 4/26
orange = 1/26
salmon = 1/26
rose = 1/26
```

That said I want to do automatically do a full description `table[2]`, meaning to cluster colours or simply count them.

Any thoughts? thanks alot

Comment: Do you want to count "Light Red", and "light red" as one category?

Comment: @akrun Well that's a good question. Yes I think I do to be honest.

Comment: @Pascal Does it really matter? I am showing you what am I using actually..

Comment: If it's a built-in function, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example data shows unequal spaces between each entry and also you have `light red`, `Light red` etc.  You don't need `clean` or `str_trim` if your actual dataset does not have the space issue.

```
 table1 <- structure(list(val = 1:26, V1 = c("soft crimson", "dark pink", 
 "watermelon", "Light Red", "dark coral", "Rose", "peach", "strawberry pink", 
 "light red", "pink", "light red", "salmon", "light red", "light red", 
 "pink", "pink", "light and unclear red", "velvet red", "light red", 
 "orange", "light red", "light  red", "light red", "dark pink", 
 "red orange", "pink")), .Names = c("val", "V1"), row.names = c(NA, 
 -26L), class = "data.frame")



 library(qdap)
 library(stringr)


 100*round(prop.table(table(clean(str_trim(toupper(table1[,2]))))),2) #in the above dataset, `str_trim` is not needed though

    #   DARK CORAL             DARK PINK LIGHT AND UNCLEAR RED 
    #            4                     8                     4 
    #    LIGHT RED                ORANGE                 PEACH 
    #           35                     4                     4 
    #          PINK            RED ORANGE                  ROSE 
    #          15                     4                     4 
    #       SALMON          SOFT CRIMSON       STRAWBERRY PINK 
    #            4                     4                     4 
    #    VELVET RED            WATERMELON 
    #             4                     4
```

Comment: were `table` you mean `table[2]`??

Comment: @Enkei, No, i meant `table()` function.  Assuming that table[2] is a vector, `lines1` is the dataset

Comment: Where do you set what object to iterate then??

Comment: how am i supposed to work with `readLines(textConnection("...")` when my text is assigned to `table[2]`? I can't just copy+paste the text into that..

Comment: @EnKei, You provided an example in a form which I read using `readLines`.  It is still not clear to others what `table[2]` is.  Is it a data.frame `column`?  Please use `dput` to show the data for helping us to help you.

Comment: you are correct its a `column` from a table created using `read.csv`. Its class is `data.frame` according to `dput`

Comment: In that case just replace `lines1` with `table[,2]` and see if that works in the code.